# Symfony 4 route annotations cause error with openapi annotations

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, symfony4, openapi

Currently our project has Symfony `4.3` installed. We have grown since `2.7` so there may be some legacy garbage but overall our app works nicely. We have a flavoring system that gets prefixed to every route (if this is a good idea I dont know but it was like this when we started supporting it). So a link would look like this:

```
test.me/{flavor}/project/{UUID}
```

We are using annotations for the routing and therefore have an `annotations.yaml`:

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/App/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix:   /{flavor}/
```

Now since we want to introduce an API documentation we wanted to use this php package: https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php which lets us write annotations for our API as we do it with routes and generates a `swagger.json` that can be distributed to our connected projects. Problem is when writing the annotations this error pops up:

```
$:bin/console cache:clear -e dev                                

 // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true                                           


In FileLoader.php line 166:

  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@OA\Schema" in class App\Controller\Api\Model\APIMessage  
   was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation? in /config/routes/../../src/Catrobat/Controller/ (which is being imported from "/config/routes/annotations.yaml"). Make sure annotations are installed  
   and enabled.
```

Any Idea how I can tell the framework to ignore this annotation in the file loader? `swagger-php` parses the files on its own so it dosent really care if this is imported or not. I also tried importing the Openapi Annotations but this did not work either. Any help into this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is somewhat embarrasing. My initial thought was, that having the `annotations.yaml` would somehow try to load the Annotations and I was correct. To resolve this errer I simply had to add:

```
use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;
```

To the files using the annotations and it works.